# iOS - CALayer and Gesture/Swipe Recognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uigesturerecognizer

I added a layer to my view to create gradient background color, but I need to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in my view. The problem is that now, with the layer, the swipe recognizer doesn't work! How can I do?? Can I add a swipe recognizer to a layer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CALayer` and its children do not support `UIGestureRecognizer`'s, only `UIView` does.  This means that you must attach gesture recognizers to some enclosing view and call [-[CALayer hitTest:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/hitTest%3a), or [-[CALayer pointInside:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/containsPoint%3a) to see which layer has been hit by a particular touch or event.