# How to remove sublayers from a view afer a touch

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in which i have a layer

layer1.frame=CGRectMake(80, 100, 180, 170);

If a user touch the screen the layer should be swiped out the the window through animation..

For this i am using a timer to animate but i don't know what to write in the timer function

to make it remove from the window(like swiped out)...

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

In Your touch event use this code:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:mysuperview duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{ [yourLayer removeFromSuperlayer]; } completion:nil]
```

Comment: Thanks...for the answer but the view is not getting swiped out it is just removing from superview...What i want is if a user touches window..the user should see the layer getting out of window(animated)

Comment: could be more specific what r using ? how many view do u have??

Comment: sir i have one view in which i am adding two layers (like squares) of different colors.What i want is if the user swipes any layer on any side..the layer should be swiped out of the window from that side..that is why i was asking that question...

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144142/ios-calayer-and-gesture-swipe-recognizer) to use swipe gesture in layer and when u get swipe gesture on layer then use code i  have given

Comment: Sir sorry but the code you have given is removing the layer ..not showing animation of the layer getting out from left or right..i want the layer to be swiped out from left,right,top,or bottom

Comment: Use this: CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.delegate = nil;
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;// Different type for deiferent animation
[theLayer addAnimation: transition forKey: nil];